# emacsclient will not allow two different frames to have the same file open

Tags: emacs

I have a problem if I do the following:

1. I start an emacs server ('emacs --daemon')
2. I start a client ('emacsclient -c') and then open the file, foo.txt.
3. I start another client ('emacsclient -c') and then attempt to switch to the already open buffer, foo.txt.

On step 3, this buffer will not open in the new frame.

Any ideas on how to allow the same buffer to be visible in two emacsclient frames?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that ido-switch-buffer was the problem.

The following fixed it:

```
(setq ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)
```